# My php gives "null" while it is something

Tags: php, arrays, json

So, I want to make my site check the bitcoin prices. I do that with virwox. So, I send a curl to `http://api.virwox.com/api/json.php?method=getBestPrices&symbols[0]=BTC/SLL`.

That gives me this:

```
{"result":[{"symbol":"BTC\/SLL","errorCode":"OK","bestBuyPrice":"983021","bestSellPrice":"1009989"}],"error":null,"id":""}
```

Now, I want the `bestBuyPrice`. So, I runned a `json_decode` on my `$output`. Then my `$output` is an array. So, I did `json_encode("$output["result"]")` to see what will come out of that. It gave me this:

```
[{"symbol":"BTC\/SLL","errorCode":"OK","bestBuyPrice":"983021","bestSellPrice":"1009989"}]
```

So, I tought if I do `json_decode("$output["bestBuyPrice"]")` I would get it, but I didn't. What I got was: `null`. How can I fix this?

Here is my full code:

```html
<?php 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.virwox.com/api/json.php?method=getBestPrices&symbols[0]=BTC/SLL"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$decode = json_decode($output, true);
$encode = json_encode($decode["result"]["bestBuyPrice"], true);
echo $encode; // Gives null

$koop = $decode["result"]["bestBuyPrice"]; // No result
$verkoop = $decode["result"]["bestSellPrice"]; // No result

echo $koop . "<br />".$verkoop;
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: the quotes, THE QUOTES

Comment: Why do you decode and then encode and then decode again…?!

Comment: @Shinratensei Sorry, I writed it wrong at my question. But in my code it is alright. No quetos still the same thing...

Comment: @deceze To check where the fault is...

Comment: `result` is an array! It has keys `0`, `1` etc, not `bestBuyPrice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one's real easy. Get rid of the quotes from around your variable!

```
json_encode("$output["result"]")
```

to

```
json_encode($output["result"])
```

EDIT:

Based on the var_dump in the comment below, it looks like there is another array key you need:

```
$koop = $decode["result"][0]["bestBuyPrice"];
```

Give that a try!

Comment: That should really result in a syntax error to begin with, not `null`…

Comment: I didn't do that in my own code. I did it in my question wrong...

Comment: What does `var_dump($decode);` give you?

Comment: That gives me this: `array(3) { ["result"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["symbol"]=> string(7) "BTC/SLL" ["errorCode"]=> string(2) "OK" ["bestBuyPrice"]=> string(6) "989000" ["bestSellPrice"]=> string(6) "996499" } } ["error"]=> NULL ["id"]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: edited my answer, give it a try

Comment: @delboy1978uk Thanks!